# Remove parallax if screen size smaller than... css only

Tags: css, parallax

I am making a parallax site using http://keithclark.co.uk/articles/pure-css-parallax-websites/.

I have finished it all and looks great, but if i resize my screen window all items inside go over each other. My question now is how can i make a responsive that 'deletes' the paralax when the screen size is about an ipad size or smaller. So that i have 'normal' pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap your code with a `@media` query, e. g.:

```
@media (min-width: 700px) {
    // your code
}
```

Then this code will only apply on a screen with a `min-width: 700px`.

Comment: not sure why this got a minus vote? The OP is using CSS paralax, this seems like the simplest answer. +1 from me.

Comment: @Aaron I don't understand it either… Glad to see that it helped. :)